# Turning off windows firewall while sharing Mysql Database through LAN?

Tags: mysql, connection, lan

In case of not turning the Firewall off:

after pinging the IP the Request time out will appears,
but after turning off the firewall it will reply.

Why?

I am using Mysql with Java, the question not related with java but maybe java programmers get something like this issues with sharing the database.

Comment: Have you tried adding MySQL and/or Java as exceptions to your Windows Firewall?

Comment: @Jamie can you explain your question more ?

Comment: Your firewall is designed to stop unauthorised connections to your computer from the network. If you haven't explicitly allowed MySQL connections through your firewall, then you won't be able to reach your MySQL server on that machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firewall will block access to port 3306 (default port for MySQL).  To get it to work without turning the firewall off, you will have to configure the firewall to let connections to port 3306 (other whatever port is configured in your `my.cnf`) through.